# Explaining Contact to a Friend in a Shortened Version

Tags: discussion

So I'm trying to explain Contact to a friend of mine. Unfortunately, I'm pretty trash at explaining rules, and they don't want to read the block of text explaining how to play Contact. A shout out to @Rand-Al-Thor btw for his explanation of Contact. It was very well done.
So my question: Can anyone give me a short, compact explanation of Contact? Thank you!

Link to the rules if anyone needs it [What are these chatrooms with names like 'Codenames', 'Contact', and 'Spyfall'? What are they for?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5985/what-are-these-chatrooms-with-names-like-codenames-contact-and-spyfall/5992#5992)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/53490?m=36418054#36418054

Comment: Sounds like your friend needs to get less lazy, and just read the rules.  They're not that complicated, and are well-stated.  Failing that, have them observe a game of Contact, and they'll quickly catch on to how it works (asking questions where necessary).

Comment: Thank you, GPR!